# Get Earth Engine Object Type

Tags: google-earth-engine

For debugging it would be great to figure out which EE object type an object is.

Example code which adds a buffer to a point in a random area:

```
var polygon = ee.Geometry.Point([0,51.477]).buffer(10000); // a circle in London
```

```js
var random_points = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(polygon.bounds(), 100); // 100 random points in London
var point_list = random_points.geometry().geometries();
print(point_list); // prints -- List (100 elements)
var one_point = point_list.get(10); // The 11th point.
print(one_point); // prints -- Point (-0.03, 51,52)
var small_circle = one_point.buffer(100);
print(small_circle); // Error -- one_point.buffer is not a function...
```

Since the console prints `Point...`, I would think that `one_point` is of type `ee.Geometry.Point`. However, according to the docs `ee.Geometry` objects are supposed to support the `.buffer()` function, which this one does not support. Hence I assume it's a different kind of object but I have no clue which. When I code in Earth Engine, I run into these kind of problems very frequently.

**Is there a way to figure out which type of EE object an object is?** Something like the fantasy `.EE_OBJECT_TYPE()` function here:

```js
print(polygon.EE_OBJECT_TYPE()); // should print -- ee.Geometry.Polygon
print(one_point.EE_OBJECT_TYPE()); // should print -- ee.WhateverObjectThisIs
```

Non-solutions:

- `print(my_object)` often indicates the type of object but, as the example above demonstrates, this is not always the case (or correct).
- `my_object.type()` only specifies the kind of `ee.Geometry` and doesn't work on any other EE objects according to the docs.
- `my_object.typeOf()` always returns `object` for EE objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`one_point.name() // ComputedObject` returns **what type this object is cast to**. From my quick tests it looks like that's the lowest-level object prototype for which `instanceof` returns true. [Source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-earth-engine-developers/get$20earth$20engine$20object$20type%7Csort:relevance/google-earth-engine-developers/DWBOBoHUAFM/qMmPY-cZCgAJ) (You need to log in to access this link but everyone working with EE can get access to this group.)

Good old `print(one_point)` returns the 'actual' object type (followed by the object itself) -- i. e. **how the object behaves**.

These can differ. To really understand an object, you'll need to call both. If you want to use the object as a function parameter for a function that only takes e.g. `ee.Geometry`, you'll need `one_point.name() === 'Geometry'.` The type indicated by `print()` tells you which functions the object supports.

These conclusions are only derived from a few tests I did and could be wrong.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is dangerously close to your non-solution, but the type of object you're dealing with is `ee.ComputedObject`.  The solution to your issue in this case is to cast to `ee.Geometry`.

```js
var polygon = ee.Geometry.Point([0,51.477]).buffer(10000); // a circle in London    
var random_points = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(polygon.bounds(), 100); // 100 random points in London
var point_list = random_points.geometry().geometries();
print(point_list); // prints -- List (100 elements)
var one_point = point_list.get(10); // The 11th point.
print(one_point); // prints -- Point (-0.03, 51,52)
var small_circle = ee.Geometry(one_point).buffer(100);
print(small_circle);

print(one_point instanceof ee.ComputedObject) // true
```

Comment: Is is a valid use-case to request the  type off ee.Object ?

Comment: This behavior is typical for the platform, there are many cases in which you have to type cast the results. For example, the List.get() function returns an Computed Object, so you have to cast the result.

Comment: Very helpful but doesn't answer the question as asked in the title and in bold. I didn't know about `instanceof` and it's pretty helpful. Thanks!
However, I'm looking for a function that returns the prototype hierarchy of an object -- i. e. all the objects (or just EE objects) for which `instanceof` would return `true`.

Comment: However, instanceof can be misleading. For instance, `ee.Geometry(ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([0,51.477])))` returns an ambiguous object. It's mostly a feature because it's printed as a feature and only supports the functions of an `ee.Feature object`. However it's an instance of `ee.Geometry` and not of `ee.Feature`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use type: type(my_object).